# Modifying class variable in function expression

Tags: javascript, scope, aurelia

I have some class variables which I want to modify in a function below but the value doesn't appear to stick.

```
export class Welcome {

  myLatitude = 0;  //I want to modify this inside activate()
  myLongitude = 0;
  myMarkers = [
  {
        latitude: -27.451673,
        longitude: 153.043981
  }
  ];

  activate() {

    var lat = this.myLatitude; // I thought this was getting a reference to myLatitude.

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ //additional function
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

        lat = latitude; // Hoping to modify myLatitude here
        ...
```

However when I check the value of myLatitude again later, it still has a value of 0:

```
  @computedFrom('myLatitude')
  get myLat() {
    console.log(this.myLatitude);
    return `${this.myLatitude}`;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `var lat = this.myLatitude` you create new independent variable. `lat` is not a link to `this.myLatitude`'s value because it has a primitive one. Only objects in JavaScript are passed by reference.

So in your case you can save a link to the context `var self = this` before `getCurrentPosition` method call and after change the value in this way `self.myLatitude = latitude`.

Or you can use an arrow function:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
  ...
  this.myLatitude = latitude;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lat = latitude; // Hoping to modify myLatitude here
```

Here, you assign the variable name `lat` to the object latitude, but you do not modify `this.myLatitude`.

I think you want to do:

```
this.myLatitude = latitude;
```

You have to read a bit about variable scope and assignation: you have to understand the difference between a variable/name and the object it points to.

Comment: I tried that like so, `this.myLatitude = latitude;` but I get an error: `TypeError: this is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this sentence

```
lat = latitude;
```

Instead of that

Try this:

```
myLatitude=latitude;
```

Comment: I gave that a try but I get this error: `ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable myLatitude`. If I try `this.myLatitude`, I get `TypeError: this is undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You could define property `myLatitude` in a ES6 class `constructor` and in your concise method `activate` you could get `myLatitude` property and change its value using `this` keyword.

Quick example:

```js
let  Welcome = class Welcome {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.myLatitude = 0;
  }
  activate() {
     this.myLatitude = '1'; // assign a new value
     alert('this.myLatitude is: ' + this.myLatitude);
  }
};

let myWelcome = new Welcome();
myWelcome.activate();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error `TypeError: this is undefined` when I try to update the value.

Comment: @Tomcelic at which line you get the error? could you provide us a snippet of your code?